# When joining table using doctrine, why do we put primaryTable.JoiningTable when we use Join or InnerJoin method?

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, doctrine-query

```
$qb->select('c')
    ->innerJoin('c.phones', 'p', 'WITH', 'p.phone = :phone')
    ->where('c.username = :username')
    ->setParameter('phone', $phone)
    ->setParameter('username', $username);
```

why do we use c.phones
when we can just use innerJoin('phones', 'p', 'WITH', 'p.phone = :phone')?

Answer (score 0):

`phones` on its own may be ambiguous if more than one entity defines `phones` property. Using `c.` gives ORM exact information what user is expecting to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question: So in doctrine we need to think in terms of entities, not worry about tables. So if phones is a reference in that entity, then you just join the table by using c.phones, doctrine will then do the magic of joining tables.